# MomentJS isAfter returning incorrect data

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to know if a date (2021-11-09) is after another date (2021-11-11) in YYYY-MM-DD format, which should be false, right ?

```
  console.log(
    moment("2021-11-09", "YYYY-MM-DD", true).isAfter(
      "2011-11-11",
      "YYYY-MM-DD",
      true
    )
  );
```

but, above code return true.

Comment: You need to convert argument of `isAfter` into moment object. `moment("2021-11-09", "YYYY-MM-DD", true).isAfter(moment("2011-11-11", "YYYY-MM-DD", true))`

Comment: @HassanImam it still return true

Comment: `2021-11-09` is after `2011-11-11`

Comment: @Sphinx omg! , what a silly typo :( . thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[the doc of momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/) states:

> If you want to limit the granularity to **a unit** other than
> milliseconds, pass the units as the second parameter.
>
> As the second parameter determines **the precision**, and not just a
> single value to check, **using day will check for year, month and
> day**

So you should use **a unit** instead of format string though it seems the result is same.

```js
console.log(
  moment("2021-11-09", "YYYY-MM-DD", true).isAfter(
    "2011-11-11",
    "day" //"YYYY-MM-DD"
  )
)
console.log(
  moment("2021-11-09", "YYYY-MM-DD", true).isAfter(
    "2021-11-11",
    "day" //"YYYY-MM-DD"
  )
)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.29.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dates you're comparing in code and the ones in your questions are not aligned. And code is returning true correctly. Because 2021-11-09 is indeed after 2011-11-11